# MySQL: How to order an SQL query result by numerical difference of multiple rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table and my goal is to search for customers that most closely resemble another given customer in how they have rated certain manufacturers. This example can be found in this [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/33fbe/6/0).

```
customer    manufacturer    rating
A           Manuf_A         8
A           Manuf_B         3
B           Manuf_A         4
B           Manuf_Y         3        
C           Manuf_X         3
C           Manuf_Y         7
D           Manuf_A         8
D           Manuf_B         7
```

**Example:**

We want to find which customers best match customer *'A'* who has a rating for two manufacturers, *manuf_A* and *manuf_B*.

**Desired results:**

```
customer    difference
D           4          
B           7
C           11
```

**Expected algorithm:**

- The smaller the difference value is, the closer related the two customers are
- If a customer doesn't share any manufacturer ratings with the subject customer, their non-existent rating should be zero instead.

B difference:

```
abs(A.manuf_A.rating (8) - B.manuf_A.rating(4)) = 4 
abs(A.manuf_B.rating (3) - B.manuf_B.rating(Doesn't exist/0)) = 3
= 4 + 3
= 7
```

C difference:

```
abs(A.manuf_A.rating (8) - C.manuf_A.rating(Doesn't exist/0)) = 8
abs(A.manuf_B.rating (3) - C.manuf_B.rating(Doesn't exist/0)) = 3
= 8 + 3
= 11
```

D difference:

```
abs(A.manuf_A.rating (8) - D.manuf_A.rating(8)) = 0
abs(A.manuf_B.rating (3) - D.manuf_A.rating(7)) = 4
= 0 + 4
= 4
```

Any advice on how this can be done in MySQL would be well received along with any suggestions of an alternative approach.

Comment: Just a comment:  This is a really well written question.  You have provided a SQL Fiddle example (that works).  You have clearly explained the problem.  As a bonus, it is an interesting problem.

Comment: [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) might be a better approach.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel . . . If it makes you feel better, this is called Manhattan distance and is perfectly reasonable for a problem like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach.  Generate all the rows for customers and the manufacturers that "A" has rated.  Then use `left join` to find the ones rated by any given customer.  The rest is just arithmetic:

```
select c.customer,
       sum(abs(am.rating - coalesce(cd.rating, 0))) as similarity
from (select cd.manufacturer, cd.rating
      from centraldatabase cd
      where cd.customer = 'A'
     ) am cross join
     customers c left join
     centraldatabase cd
     on cd.manufacturer = am.manufacturer and cd.customer = c.customer
group by c.customer
order by similarity asc;
```

Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a43fbd/1).  Note:  I don't know if it is a good idea to create your own schema in SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Thanks a lot, for the quick response and because this works great! Relatively new to MySQL so I will happily 
spend a bit of time digesting what's going on here :) Ah yes, that schema creation would explain a few oddities!